# Product of Two subnormal subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group  $H$ and $K$ be its subgroup then i know

$a$) $HK$ need not be a subgroup of $G$.

$b$) But if any one say $H$ is normal in $G$ than $ HK \leq G$.

$c$) If $H$ and $K$ both are normal in $G$ than $HK$ is normal in $G$

now my question is:

> Is the product of two subnormal subgroup of a group $G$ forms a subgroup again.If no than can you give me a counterexample.If yes then is it subnormal or narmal in $G$ or just a subgroup.

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite $p$-group, every subgroup is subnormal, so this is a good place to look for counter-examples. Consider, for example, the respective groups generated by non-commuting involutions in a dihedral group of order 8...